# ¿Cuál es la forma adecuada de crear eventos en JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Quiero presentar mi problema con respecto a los eventos con JavaFx. Me sucede que al crear un evento este ejecuta las acciones sin ningún problema, el caso es que tengo que dar doble clic siempre, y no creo que esto sea necesario, creo que estoy haciendo algo mal con respecto a mi código, he buscado en la documentación, he seguido los tutoriales de dicha documentación, pero el problema persiste y no sé el por qué, aquí anexo el código de mi FXMLController:

```
public class LoginViewController implements Initializable {

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 *
 * @param url
 * @param rb
 */
private Conexion conexion = new Conexion();
private Empleado empleadoGenerico = new Empleado();

@FXML private JFXTextField textoNombreUsuario;
@FXML private JFXPasswordField textoConstrasena;
@FXML private JFXButton btnLoginIngresar;
@FXML private ImageView imgCarga;
@FXML private Label msgUsuarioNoExiste;
@FXML private Label msgContrasenaIncorrecta;
@FXML private Label msgFaltanDatos;

@FXML public void inicioSesion() {

    btnLoginIngresar.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {

        if (textoNombreUsuario.getText().equals("") || textoConstrasena.getText().equals("")) {
            msgContrasenaIncorrecta.setVisible(false);
            msgUsuarioNoExiste.setVisible(false);
            msgFaltanDatos.setVisible(true);
        } else {

            if (textoNombreUsuario.getText().length() > 0 && textoConstrasena.getText().length() > 0) {

                empleadoGenerico.getUsuario().setNombreUsuario(textoNombreUsuario.getText());
                empleadoGenerico.getUsuario().setContrasena(textoConstrasena.getText());
                InicioSesion.loginIn(conexion.getConexion(), empleadoGenerico, 
                        textoNombreUsuario, textoConstrasena, 
                        msgUsuarioNoExiste, msgContrasenaIncorrecta, msgFaltanDatos);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    conexion.Conexion();
}
```

}

Estoy trabajando con Scene Builder, aquí es donde llamo el método creado en el FXMLController:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí mi código del botón .FXML:

```
<JFXButton fx:id="btnLoginIngresar" layoutX="156.0" layoutY="238.0" onMouseClicked="#inicioSesion" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="101.0" style="-fx-background-color: #5FC5F5;" styleClass="Fuente" text="Ingresar" textFill="WHITE">
                 <font>
                    <Font name="Poiret One" size="16.0" />
                 </font>
                 <cursor>
                    <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                 </cursor>
</JFXButton>
```

De antemano gracias por sus aportes, y cualquier recomendación con respecto a la creación de eventos en JavaFX es recibida. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero es que hay que matizar que estas utilizando la librería JFoenix. Una vez dicho esto, el principal problema es que desde el fichero FXML indicas que el controlador del evento es la función "inicioSesion()", pero una vez que lanzas esa funcion, sobreescribes el controlador del evento onClickMouse cuando haces:

```js
btnLoginIngresar.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {
```

La solución es sencilla, tienes que eliminar las líneas que te voy a indicar a continuación dentro de la función "inicioSesion".

```js
@FXML public void inicioSesion() {

    // Se elimina esta linea --> btnLoginIngresar.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {

        if (textoNombreUsuario.getText().equals("") || textoConstrasena.getText().equals("")) {
            msgContrasenaIncorrecta.setVisible(false);
            msgUsuarioNoExiste.setVisible(false);
            msgFaltanDatos.setVisible(true);
        } else {

            if (textoNombreUsuario.getText().length() > 0 && textoConstrasena.getText().length() > 0) {

                empleadoGenerico.getUsuario().setNombreUsuario(textoNombreUsuario.getText());
                empleadoGenerico.getUsuario().setContrasena(textoConstrasena.getText());
                InicioSesion.loginIn(conexion.getConexion(), empleadoGenerico, 
                        textoNombreUsuario, textoConstrasena, 
                        msgUsuarioNoExiste, msgContrasenaIncorrecta, msgFaltanDatos);
            }
        }
    // Se elimina esta linea --> });
}
```

De esta forma se va a comportar como quieres, ya que el problema de sobreescritura de controladores ya no ocurre.

Comment: Entiendo, claro ahora veo la sobre escritura :(  muchas gracias por aclararme ese inconveniente. Me solucionaste un problema que llevo hace rato teniendo.